# Use arrow function instead of function expression - tslint error

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, tslint

Having tslint warnings (ES6) and still having some difficulty with its syntax.I am not sure how to convert to arrow functions.

[Image show the occurred warning][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCY69.png

```
var options = this.state.ProjectsArray.map(function (item, i) {
  var Trmp = item["ID"] + ";#" + item["Title"];
  return <option value={Trmp} key={item["ID"]}>{item["Title"]}</option> ;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

```
var options = this.state.ProjectsArray.map((item, i) => {
  var Trmp = item["ID"] + ";#" + item["Title"];
  return <option value={Trmp} key={item["ID"]}>{item["Title"]}</option> ;
});
```

Remove `function` word and put `=>` after the parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot.! Worked well.

Comment: May I know what's the cause behind? TS version issue?